# When is setting $JAVA_HOME required/helpful?

Tags: java, installation, macos-big-sur, java-home

Some tutorials set $JAVA_HOME env variable on MacBook Pro (macOS Big Sur-Zsh) and some don't. When is setting $JAVA_HOME required/helpful?

Comment: Some apps will check it, rather than looking for Java in your path. That's literally the only reason. If you don't seem to have any app that's checking it (i.e. nothing is failing with something like "$JAVA_HOME is not set") then don't bother. I never normally set it and don't often have any issue

Comment: If the software you're using specifically says it needs `JAVA_HOME` set to a value.  Otherwise it will do nothing.